# Chain `drawtext` with ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have a function within my python script to loop through some given text via an API but I am having issues drawing multiple text values:-

```
def add_text(title, text_lines):
    input = ffmpeg.input(f'output/{title}.mp4')
    for text in text_lines:
        output = input.drawtext(
            fontsize='24',
            start_number=0,
            text=text['text'],
            fontcolor='white',
            escape_text=True
        )
    ffmpeg.output(output, f'output/{title}-final.mp4').run()
```

This works if I have a single test value passed into the loop, but if I pass 2 or more values only the last value is drawn onto the video.

How am I able to loop through the `text_lines` and build up the output to include all of the values in the outputted file.

the array for text_lines looks like:-

```
[{text: 'Value 1'}, {text: 'Value 2'}, {text: 'Value 3',}]
```

I know they will be overlapping each other but that is not the issue at the moment, just the values apart from the last is not being shown on the video.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are lucky that at least works with one value. For me it doesn't work at all. I don't see any text in the PNG image I tried with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reassign input (or use an intermediate variable). What's happening in each loop is you are taking the *fresh* `input` and drawing the text over that.

You could do something like

```
...
        input = input.drawtext(
...
```

I believe, though I haven't worked with videos much. Like, you might need to do more to make sure the text doesn't all just layer over itself.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just testing now, I will let you know of the outcome.

Comment: glad to hear it!!

Comment: How can you use a keyword like 'input' as a variable? Don't you know that after that you can't use the 'input()' function anymore? This is a huge mistake. And you got upvotes for your answer. Lucky that that people in don't know better! I should downvote you --which is a stupid and uneducative idea-- but I prefer indicating the mistake.